# PouchDB with Windows Java development

Tags: java, database, eclipse, pouchdb

I'm currently involved with a course teaching Java, and unfortunately equipment limitations mean that the more appropriate database solutions such as SQL Server or MySQL aren't an option. I'm resorting to PouchDB, but this approach is also problematic:

1: We don't have a version of Eclipse with Web Tools here, just the basic copy of Eclipse Mars. How can we use PouchDB without a web handler?

2: There is a lot of documentation surrounding the use of PouchDB with Java, but it's primarily Android based. What should we be aware of when using PouchDB under Windows?

Comment: I'm not quite sure if you really want to go with PouchDB in your situation... It's an [in-browser database](https://pouchdb.com/learn.html). I guess your confusing PouchDB with CouchDB, which is a stand-alone database, that you can install on your PC or laptop. If that's the case check out the [getting started with Java](https://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Getting_started_with_Java).

Comment: @Phonolog Thanks, this is good information. Does CouchDB work in the same manner? I.E as a flat file that accepts sql-like methods?

Comment: I'm not an expert on CouchDB, but it should come as a service and store it's data in a .couch-file. The API should also be pretty similar... See the first sentence [here](https://pouchdb.com/guides/setup-couchdb.html#couchdb-pouchdbs-older-sibling)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to store PouchDB data in a Java app, you should most likely be using CouchDB with [Ektorp](https://github.com/helun/Ektorp) instead.

PouchDB does not have any Java version or Java wrappers other than [PouchDroid](https://github.com/nolanlawson/PouchDroid) which is deprecated.